LP duality for approximate bounded degree
$\begin{align*}
 &\text{min } \epsilon \\
 &|f(x) - \sum_{|S|\leq d} c_S \chi_S(x)| \leq \epsilon, \ \ \ x \in D \\
 &|\sum_{|S| \leq d} c_S \chi_S(x)| \leq 1 + \epsilon, \ \ \ x \in \{-1,1\}^n \setminus D\\
 &\epsilon \geq 0
\end{align*}$
Consider this primal LP where $p(x) = \sum_{|S|\leq d} c_S \chi_S(x)$ is a multilinear polynomial of degree $\leq d$, and minimization is over $\epsilon \ and \ c_S$.
It is given that the dual LP for this is given by
$\begin{align*}
  &\text{max } \sum_{x \in D} f(x)\phi(x) - \sum_{x \in \{-1,1\}^n\setminus D} |\phi(x)|\\
 &\sum_{x \in \{-1,1\}^n} |\phi(x)| = 1\\
 & \sum_{x \in \{-1,1\}^n} \phi(x)\chi_S(x) = 0, \ \ \ for \ all \ |S| \leq d \\
 & \phi(x) \in \mathbb{R}\\
\end{align*}$
Can someone explain how is this the dual of the primal LP?
